# Timed response not working messenger bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am working on a facebook messenger bot using node.js. I am trying to get my code to send a timed response to the user but it is not working. Here is the code:

```
function handlePostback(sender_psid, received_postback) {
let response;
let subscribe;

// Get the payload for the postback
let payload = received_postback.payload;

// Set the response based on the postback payload
if (payload === 'yes') {
  response = { "text": "Thanks! Here's your first task : Hold the door for someone. " };
  subscribe = true;
} else if (payload === 'no') {
  response = {"text":"That's unfortunate" };
  subscribe = false;
}

// Send the message to acknowledge the postback
callSendAPI(sender_psid, response);

  if (subscribe===true) {
    response = {"text":"Today's task will be:"};
    setTimeout(sendTask(), 5000);
  }

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborated on 'it is not working'. Is there an error? It's not clear what is supposed to happen. You set `response` twice when `payload == yes`, but the second time is in a timeout, which means it will fire after `callSendAPI`.

Comment: No, it's not showing an error.

Comment: @Mark_M The setTime out function is supposed to send the response to the person who sent the message. I know that the function works but it's not sending the response to the user. Everything else is working fine.

Comment: @Mark_M Made an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using a different send function for the timed response.